# SocketTimeoutException crashes the app

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm getting fatal error when I use my app, than I set my phone to airplane mode to emulate no internet connection and when I open the fragment with internet requests I get a crash. Please help me to solve this problem. I have no idea how and where I can catch or handle that exception.

Thanks for advice

the place where the code runs

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


    sharedSessionDataStorage.cardProvider
            .getCardProvider()
            .bindToLifecycle(this)
            .doFinally { stopProgress() }
            .subscribe({
                stopProgress()
                updateCardAdapter(it)
            }, {
                stopProgress()
                Ln.e(it)
            })

}
```

my list of dependencies is

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
```

error log:

```
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.780ms
W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:230)
W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:275)
W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:243)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:345)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:217)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:211)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:75)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
W/System.err:     at com.ihsanbal.logging.LoggingInterceptor.intercept(LoggingInterceptor.java:56)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
W/System.err:     at com.readystatesoftware.chuck.ChuckInterceptor.intercept(ChuckInterceptor.java:172)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap.subscribeActual(ObservableMap.java:32)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$1.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:39)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: io.app.dev.debug, PID: 17950
                  java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
                      at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:230)
                      at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:275)
                      at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:243)
                      at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:345)
                      at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:217)
                      at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:211)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:75)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                      at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                      at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                      at com.ihsanbal.logging.LoggingInterceptor.intercept(LoggingInterceptor.java:56)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                      at com.readystatesoftware.chuck.ChuckInterceptor.intercept(ChuckInterceptor.java:172)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                      at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
                      at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
                      at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
                      at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)
                      at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
                      at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
                      at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
                      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap.subscribeActual(ObservableMap.java:32)
                      at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
                      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
                      at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
                      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnEach.java:42)
                      at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10179)
                      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$1.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:39)
                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17950 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post the code where the api is called to get the result

Comment: done, but it's not useful, since logs doesn't show the error place in my code and OnError method doesn't fire in that case :(

Comment: can you just post full code?

Comment: full code of what? There is a simple fragment, simple list adapter which populated by request as I posted or where the bottleneck could be?

Comment: full code of `sharedSessionDataStorage.cardProvider
            .getCardProvider()`, it might be crucial for understanding the problem.

Comment: @yosriz a lot of thanks, you showed me right direction :) and I found the reason of it

Comment: you are welcome to share the problem for future generations to come...

Comment: I neglected Rx contact and tried to use provider observable after onError() was called

Comment: @Gorets can you add an answer explaining how you fixed this issue?

Comment: @W.K.S I was misunderstanding Rx concept. I tried to build chain of event after subscription has ended. You'd better create new question with your problem

Comment: Did you fix this? We are having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just Tried Out this Error Handler on Rx java >2.0 looks like this error handler resolved the socket Timeouts

Check this Answer
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54250447/9901309

RX documentation
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54250447/9901309